# windows dhcp server add static arp

Tags: dhcp-server, arp

in our network, Windows DHCP server 2008 broadcast Gateway's IP as router, recently some Laptop Client (most of them has personal ESET firewall installed by owners) start to get wrong arp for gateway, they get gateway interface2 MAC address with interface1 IP, so can't connect to internet, can I add static arp for gateway address in DHCP or must do something else?
gateway's interface1 is connected to LAN, interface2 is in other range address and network between gateway and modem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use technology like hotspare for your gateway ? (HRSP)

Comment: Yes gatway that I mentioned is Kerio control